# How to detect the current charging state in android

Tags: java, c#, android

I am new in android. I want to make an app with a service. The service should continuously check the current charging state(Plugged or not). And I want to perform an event(Turn wifi off) when the charger is connected. Can you please solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you call the function below it can show if the device is charging. You can use that to perform the tasks you need: (This will work for both wired and wireless charging)

```
public static boolean isPlugged(Context context) {
boolean isPlugged= false;
Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
isPlugged = plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC || plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
if (VERSION.SDK_INT > VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    isPlugged = isPlugged || plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS;
}
return isPlugged;
}
```

For more information [visit the Android Dev site here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html).

Comment: Can i use this in background. Also i want to check it repeatedly. It should detect the charging state at the moment of plugging.

Comment: You should try that yourself

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the battery status you can find an examples below:

You can check battery status on-demand:

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);


int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                 status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;


int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;`
```

Or by using BroadcastReceiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The Code:

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                        status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
    int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
}
}
```

In order to turn WIFI programmatic -

You should define the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

To set it On:

```
 WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

To Set it Off:

```
 WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

Comment: But how can i check it repeatedly in background.

Comment: Hi, I believe that you have all info, you can do it repeatedly by taken the information from the broadcast receiver for example by checking the usbCharge status, or make a function that return the usbCharge  at on-demand example .